# PHP blank page upon scraper script completion

Tags: php

I have a script for scraping products details (name, prices, etc.). Codes mainly using curl and loops for extracting data.

When scraping small number of products, the output is displayed properly in web browsers. However, when it is processing a lot of products, Mozilla never finished loading and Chrome displays a blank page after it is finished, no output displayed. I tried dumping the output into a txt file and everything is captured as intended, just the html part does not show up in browsers.

I thought it is timeout issue so I set the followings;

```
ini_set('max_execution_time','0');
ini_set('max_input_time','0');
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

..and still no luck.

I don't really know where to troubleshoot this. Is it PHP or Apache issue? Any hints is appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the relevant part of your PHP code? Are you doing the scraping in the same script as your browser output? That might be a problem - scraping is usually a offline process, and simply reported on by web-side scripts.

Comment: I played around and found that it was actually Apache issue.

Comment: Yes, it is actually a single PHP script taking input with `$_GET` then displays the output in semi-colon separated values. On large requests it may take up to 15 minutes, hence the timed out web server. I think I will run the scraping process in the background and dump the output into a .csv file, then provide users a link to that file. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Good idea. You can run it from a job server, such as Gearman, or simply on a timer, such as cron. The results it writes to the database can be looked up in a web application using an ordinary query, which will remove the time-out problem. (If you get a moment, do please copy your solution into an answer box and accept it. We welcome self-answered questions here, and once it is ticked, it is removed from the unanswered lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with Apache, and not PHP. I increased the value of `TimeOut` in httpd.conf and things are now working properly.